# VM aborting while creating two threads in android application

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have created one thread for calling native function which are calling the MPEG2 codec which is developed in C. And callback_handler is calling java function for giving image frame and handler is displaying the frames on image view. And it is working fine. but when I am trying to create two threads for calling native function for each thread and displaying two videos.I have created two handlers for each thread. but when I started the application it is calling native methods two times but after some function execution I am getting **VM Aborting** error. I have searched for that problem. And I found that one JNIEnv can have only one thread.And for that we should register thread JNIEnv with JavaVM. In callback_handler I am doing that by using this function

```
JNIEnv *env = RegisterWithVM(&jvm);
    if((NULL == env) || (NULL == jvm))
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"JNI", "callback_handler call failed\n");
        return;
    }
```

And I have also tried to attch the currentThread Enviroment with JavaVM in JNi native function using that code.

```
gJavaVM->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
gJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
```

But after using this I am getting this error.

```
11-28 16:40:23.430: I/JNI(323): Loaded
11-28 16:40:23.430: I/JNI(323): Find the class
11-28 16:40:23.430: I/JNI(323): Registered...
11-28 16:40:23.430: I/JNI(323): Version...65540
11-28 16:40:23.440: I/JNI(323): CallDecoding function of thread is called
11-28 16:40:23.451: I/JNI(323): StartDecoding function is called
11-28 16:40:23.451: W/dalvikvm(323): JNI WARNING: threadid=7 using env from threadid=8
11-28 16:40:23.451: W/dalvikvm(323):              in Lcom/example/Internet_TV12;.CallDecoding1 (ILjava/lang/Object;)V (NewByteArray)
11-28 16:40:23.451: I/dalvikvm(323): "Thread-8" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
11-28 16:40:23.451: I/dalvikvm(323):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44ee97f0 self=0x131cc0
11-28 16:40:23.470: I/JNI(323): CallDecoding function of thread is called
11-28 16:40:23.470: I/JNI(323): In JNI interface image file opened 
11-28 16:40:23.470: I/JNI(323): StartDecoding function is called

11-28 16:40:23.499: I/dalvikvm(323):   | sysTid=331 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1153704
11-28 16:40:23.499: I/dalvikvm(323):   | schedstat=( 28746111 138980250 15 )
11-28 16:40:23.499: I/dalvikvm(323):   at com.example.Internet_TV12.CallDecoding1(Native Method)
11-28 16:40:23.499: I/dalvikvm(323):   at com.example.Internet_TV12$4.run(Internet_TV12.java:57)
11-28 16:40:23.499: I/dalvikvm(323):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-28 16:40:23.499: E/dalvikvm(323): VM aborting
```

Can any body please help me to resolve this problem...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you overwrite your env variable and then use it again in different thread.

Comment: firstly i would like to say thanks for your response. So can you please tell me what should I do for that. Should I require to create another native callDecoding function (JNI native method)for second thread. I have tried that also. But got the same error.

Comment: You should connect your env variable in appropriate thread context, eg. right after thread start call AttachCurrentThread. Value of obtained environment must be used in current thread context only. Not sure, that this is a reason of your issue, but try.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have some doubt about your response. Firstly I want to ask where should I call AttachCurrentThread in native call or in callback_handler? My native method is calling other C functions and giving data to callback_handler. Can you please paste some code for developing the concept what you are trying to say.